# Is Tomcat 8 reading the web.xml and context.xml files in my Java Rest API (war)?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, tomcat8

I created a Java Rest API (Dynamic Web) project in Eclipse (including Javax and Jersey libraries) and deployed it to my Tomcat 8 server.

It returns a basic JSON response when I call it via HTTP (e.g. `http://www.mydomain.co.uk:8080/MyJavaProject/context_string/path_params`), but when I enable SSL/TLS on the server, with a genuine certificate, it gives a `404 Not Found` in Postman.

`error.log` shows a `file does not exist` error on `/path/MyJavaProject/context_string/path_params`, but the file doesn't exist as it's a reference param in my REST API, so I don't think Tomcat knows to use the WAR file.

I can get to the directory structure navigator if I call `https://www.mydomain.co.uk/MyJavaProject`.

My logs are all OK and show no errors now. I have put the security values in my `web.xml` in my app's `WEB-INF`. Permissions on the `WAR` and its exploded folder are all `777`.

I have read that something called `context.xml` is used in this area, but may or may not be used if `autoDeploy-true` is set (mine is).

My question is: how can I find out if Tomcat is actually reading the `context.xml` and `web.xml` in my app?  This is my last idea to try and resolve my 404 error.

Here is my app's `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>MyProject</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/context_string/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Here is my app's `context.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="" path="" reloadable="true">
</Context>
```

Comment: Tell us more about your setup. Have you enabled HTTPS on tomcat or a front end server placed in front of tomcat?

Comment: I believe i have enabled on Tomcat itself. Setup *.443 VirtualHost in conf file, and also 8443 Connectors in server.xml, as per forum posts. When i enter URL in browser (where i get the WAR files director structure) it shows as 'Secure' and i can see the correct certificate being used.

Comment: There is a conflict in port numbers. Either use 8443 both in VirtualHost and Connectors or use 443 both in VirtualHost and Connectors.

Comment: I replaced 8443 to 443 in .conf but didn’t notice a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem using both of the comments on this call.

1. There was a port conflict, so i changed both server.xml and apache2/../000default.conf to use 8443 (i found 443 temperamental).
   Going along with this, i include '8443' as the port in all my URL calls now, rather than no port.
2. I added this to .conf file:

   SSLProxyEngine on

   ProxyPass /MyProject/context https://www.mydomain.co.uk/MyProject/context

   ProxyPassReverse /MyProject/context https://www.mydomain.co.uk/MyProject/context
3. Had to also
   a2enmod proxy_http
   and
   set VirtualHost tag to be ip and not '*', ie ipaddress.8443
   and for good measure, check it works using

apache2ctl configtest

I didnt really do much more with the web.xml in my app and i removed the context.xml from my app.

It was really a case of tweaks the knobs and dials until it worked, and took me about 2 weeks. Why can't it be easy.

Here are my files for reference

apache2/..conf

```
<VirtualHost ipaddress:8443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

        LogLevel debug
        #SetEnv HTTPS on
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_co_uk.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.mydomain.co.uk.key
       # SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_co_uk.pem
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_co_uk.ca-bundle
        ServerName www.mydomain.co.uk
SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass /MyProject/context https://www.mydomain.co.uk/MyProject/context 
    ProxyPassReverse /MyProject/context https://www.mydomain.co.uk/MyProject/context

Alias /ProjectName"/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ProjectName"


<Directory "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ProjectName">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Allow from all
</Directory>



<Location />
Require all granted
</Location>



        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Server.xml

```
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200" clientAuth="false"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="/etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_co_uk.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="/etc/ssl/private/www.mydomain.co.uk.key"
           SSLPassword="planetx"
           SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"/>


    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

web.xml from my apps web-inf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Projectname</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>Projectname</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/context</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Comment: IMHO - it is not that difficult once you understand proxy, reverse proxy, connectors, their ports and how to orchestrate them to achieve the end result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reverse proxy in apache2 or nginx whatever you're using to internally redirect reqests to tomcat.

https uses 443 port as default on server. So either you need to define a new port with https or redirect same.
Read [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) and [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) to change in apache2.

This is more like a comment but I am not able to add a comment.

Comment: I'll try this. I did see a post last night where someone had 'reverse proxy' tags in (i think it was) conf file, so i'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Implemented this and it made the error go away in the error.log. Systemctl config shows that it’s ‘ok’. All the logs look happy. I can see changes to the reverseproxy value changes the 404 browser error. But the 404 is still there when I use Postman. I’m still thinking I’m missing something in my web.xml or (now removed) context.xml. Thanks